# What exactly is difference between "Implicit function" and "Multivalued function"?

Tags: calculus, functions

I am confused what exactly is the difference between **"[Implicit function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function)"** and **"[Multivalued function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function)"**?

I think that implicit functions are multivalued functions but **mostly polynomials**, but multivalued functions are generally any function (And not necessarily polynomial) that associates multiple values ​​to each input in the domain. Am I right?

Comment: Implicit functions are genuine functions for one thing. “Implicit function” just refers to a function $\varphi$ obtained by the implicit function theorem as a local solution to the equation $F(x,\varphi(x))=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Implicit function" is used to describe a situation in which each admissible value of a variable (say, $x$) gives exactly one value of another variable (say, $y$), but where you are not given an *explicit* definition in the form
$$y=f(x)\ ,$$
that is, $y$ in terms of $x$.

**Example**.  The equation
$$2y+\sin y=x$$
defines $y$ implicitly as a function of $x$, because for every real value of $x$ there is exactly one value of $y$ which satisfies the equation.  (Exercise: prove that this is true!)

Comment: So can it be said that an implicit function is not a multivalued function?

Comment: @amin locally an implicit function is a function. Globally it may be multi valued if you abuse terminology